# cannot find module '@babel/helper-regex' require stack

Tags: reactjs

I am working on this React project which i did the following steps in the project root folder.

1. yarn
2. yarn start

and it compiles and runs the first time successfully. However, after code changes (no new libraries were added), during compilation this error comes up:

> ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js Error: [BABEL]
> C:\Users\user\Documents\react_project\node_modules\react-dev-utils\webpackHotDevClient.js:
> Cannot find module '@babel/helper-regex'

And i end up having to delete the entire node_modules and re download.. Does anyone have idea why this happens?

Comment: Hey it would be great if you can link your repo on Github and give more info about your project and hardware your'e working on. 

Btw, I've deleted the `node_modules` and installed packages again and indeed – this error was fixed by those steps.

Comment: what about `yarn add @babel/helper-regex` ?

Answer (score 9):

Delete the `node_modules` folder and reinstall them.
This worked for me. I hope it can work for you too.

Answer (score 4):

```
yarn add @babel/helper-regex
```

comes to mind at first glance
but did you get any workable solution?

Answer (score 0):

It might be issue with `node_modules`.
You can resolve this issue by the following steps,

- Delete `node_modules` folder from the project directory.
- Delete all lock files like `package-lock.json`, `yarn.lock` etc.
- Install node_modules using `npm install` command instead of `yarn install`.